# How to define environement variable with the same command line on both Unix and Windows? (set/export)

Tags: bash, shell, npm, terminal, environment-variables

On Windows I have to use a command like this:

```
set FOO=BAR && npm run something
```

But on Unix `set` is not defining the environment variable. I therefore have to use `export` instead but `export` only works on Unix.

I end up having two different commands for Unix and Windows which is not ideal...

Question: How can I have a command that define an environement variable for both on Windows and UNIX?

Comment: They are different systems completely, why is only one command needed or why would it even be possible?

Comment: @ou2s : This is a bit like asking how to write a statement which is valid in C++ and in LISP. If you consider it a nuisance to maintain two different definitions in sync, consider defining your own file format for defining such an association (similar to an INI-file or Java property file, or maybe JSON), and write a parser which translates it to the respective target formats.

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure separate operating systems that have separate commands using one same command - in some rare and specific cases it can be done (look up *polyglot*), but not in general.

Could you use something other than environment variables? Often this issue is solved by having project files for synthetic/faked "environment" variables, such as having a `.env` file.

Answer (score 1):

Although bash and cmd are different languages and system are different and it makes sense to write different scripts the following polyglot should work.

Note that `set` is a bash built-in but defining the function `set` will take precedence (see `type -a set`), and `builtin set ..` allows to call builtin

```
echo ; set() { export "$1";} #>NUL
set FOO=BAR && npm run something
```